# Getting Multiple Related Counts On SQL Table

Tags: sql, sqlite, relational-database

I am attempting to get a count of all rides which have a city as a from location, and a to location.

My tables are similar to this:

rides: rno (int), src (from location lcode), dst (to location lcode)

locations: lcode (str), prov (str), city (str)

I want to return a list of the city and province, and the count of rides that have that city as the "src" location, and the count of rides that have that city as the "dst" location.

I attempted to model it like this:

```
SELECT
    l.city,
    l.prov,
    COUNT(rsrc.rno)
FROM
    locations l
    LEFT OUTER JOIN rides rsrc ON l.lcode = rsrc.src
GROUP BY
    l.city
```

This works perfectly and returns the right data set:

```
Calgary|Alberta|3
Edmonton|Alberta|37
Jasper|Alberta|0
Regina|Saskatchewan|1
Saskatoon|Saskatchewan|1
Vancouver|British Columbia|1
```

however when I try to join rides again to get the dst as well, the results are all wrong:

```
SELECT
    l.city,
    l.prov,
    COUNT(rsrc.rno),
    COUNT(rdst.rno)
FROM
    locations l
    LEFT OUTER JOIN rides rsrc ON l.lcode = rsrc.src
    LEFT OUTER JOIN rides rdst ON l.lcode = rdst.dst
GROUP BY
    l.city
```

The result of that query is:

```
Calgary|Alberta|19|21
Edmonton|Alberta|86|96
Jasper|Alberta|0|0
Regina|Saskatchewan|1|1
Saskatoon|Saskatchewan|2|2
Vancouver|British Columbia|1|3
```

The results don't make sense to me, so I assume that I am doing something logically wrong but I don't know what. Could someone tell me why this is giving me undesired results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution is to use `count(distinct)`:

```
SELECT l.city, l.prov,
       COUNT(DISTINCT rsrc.rno), COUNT(DISTINCT rdst.rno)
FROM locations l LEFT JOIN
     rides rsrc
     ON l.lcode = rsrc.src LEFT JOIN
     rides rdst
     ON l.lcode = rdst.dst
GROUP BY l.city, l.prov;
```

The problem is that your joins are causing Cartesian products.  `COUNT()` is simply counting the number of matched values -- but matches to `rscr` are being multiplied by what is happening at `rdst` and vice versa.

Comment: Yes that works. Could you briefly explain why? each joined set should only have the certain number as defined on the join but it returns way more.